# Getting Cast to Array failed for value "[object Object]" at pathexception on node.js

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am sending formData containing data and file togehter, using angularJs to node server.

- When I am posting data with `productName,description,car,fileNames`, then I am able to post data to database.
- When I am sending data with `productName,description,car,fileNames` along with `productStock`, then node server is throwing exception,

  > Image validation failed: productStock: Cast to Array failed for value "[object Object]" at path "productStock"

**Model**

```
var mongoose=require('mongoose');
var Schema=mongoose.Schema;

    var imageSchema=new Schema({
        productName:{type: String, require: false},
        description:{type: String,required: false},
        car:{type: String,required: false},
        imagePaths: [{type: String,required: false}],
        productStock: [
        {
            size: {type: Number, required: false},
            quantity: {type: Number, required: false}

        }
        ]
    });
```

**Angular controller:**

```
var formData = new FormData();
                for(key in $scope.product){
                  formData.append(key, $scope.product[key]);
                  console.log('FormData:' + $scope.product[key])
                }
$http.post('http://localhost:3000/image/upload',formData,{
                  transformRequest: angular.identity,
                  headers:{
                            'Content-Type': undefined
                  }
                }).then(function(res){

                });
```

Why this is happening, please help.

Comment: It seems like you are sending an object in productStock while in schema productStock is defined as Array. Should it be object or Array?

Comment: it's array in schema, but how I am sending object?

Comment: It's hard to tell. It is not visible here where the data productStock come from. What does console.log say?

Comment: on angular side console.log prints [object object].